Azure AD permissions for MS Forms
Can`t find permissions for https://forms.office.com/.default
Could someone help me with this? What did I miss? Why can't I see permissions for forms?  At least Forms.Read or something. I’m reading the tutorials for 2023, they were still there

Can you edit the question to include the "tutorials" you were referring to? Things are moving fast, so tutorials can go out-of-date quickly.

Somewhere here : https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-forms/api-to-access-ms-forms/m-p/1463830

Navigate to your Registered App --> API Permission --> Add Permission --> APIs my organization uses --> Search for Microsoft Forms

Let me know, Is this work for you or not?

@PratikJadhav looks good, thanks

Initially, Registered Microsoft Entra ID  App for Single Tenant:

After, that Add API Permission for Microsoft Forms:


Note: Type of permission depends on which flow you are using for generating access token.
Delegated Permission : Authorization Code Flow.
Application Permission : Client Credentials Flow.
For Forms.Read , Delegated Permission, where user-interaction needed.


Can we do it without user interaction? Let`s say with "Delegated access, an app acting on behalf of a signed-in user."
